# Unable to execute batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I have this set of java codes:

```
public class OpenBatchFile {
public OpenBatchFile() {
    super();
}

/**Main Method
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Get Runtime object
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        //Pass string in this format to open Batch file
        runtime.exec("cmd /c start Desktop:\\OpenNotepad.bat");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

When i type `start Desktop:\\OpenNotepad.bat` command on cmd, access is denied. I get an error stating:

> There is no program associated to perform the requested action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel.

What do i have to add in my codes to execute the OpenNotepad.bat file? Someone please help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Consider [Apache Commons Exec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/). It is robust and reliable library to execute external apps from a java application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `cmd`, there is nothing like `Desktop:\\OpenNotepad.bat`. You probably want:

```
start "" "%desktop%\OpenNotepad.bat"
```

given, `%desktop%` is defined. If not, use

```
start "" "%homepath%\desktop\OpenNotepad.bat"
```

or just

```
"%desktop%\OpenNotepad.bat"
```

or

```
"%homepath%\desktop\OpenNotepad.bat"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

`%UserProfile%\Desktop\`